# Pydub for python 2.7 [windows 7]

Tags: python, pydub

How do I download and install `pydub` module to use in Python 2.7 on Windows 7 machine?

What I found was the instructions for UNIX users only.

[I want to concatenate two audio files (.wma). I found no solution code using the built-in modules so I decided to use `pydub` instead.

**However** if there is an easier way to merge audio files, using built-in modules, I would be eager to know about it.]

Answer (score 1):

First [install pip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12476379/6024712) if you dont already have it

then do this:

```
pip install pydub
```

or

```
pip install git+https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub.git@master
```

or

```
git clone https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub.git
```

Comment: I wanted instructions for a WIndows 7 machine

Comment: i don't get the part "from the python directory"

Comment: like this `C:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe`

Comment: did you see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows/12476379#12476379 ?

Comment: actually pip is already installed if you're using Python 2 >=2.7.9 or Python 3 >=3.4 downloaded from python.org, but you'll need to upgrade pip.

Comment: i have python 2.7.8 as well as python 3.3

Comment: is there not any easier way to concatenate audio (.wma OR .mp3 OR .wav) files?